# console.log is an Unexpected Identifier in node

Tags: node.js

I trying to run a basic node app.  I just want to print the contents of my `stdin`.  Here is the code:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) 
   console.log("recieved " + data)
});

process.stdin.emit('data', 'abc');
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
   console.log("recieved " + data)
   ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Why is `node` not recognizing my `console.log`?

Comment: You're missing an opening curly brace. `process.stdin.on("data", function(data) {`

Comment: Syntax errors point to where the issue has become obvious to the parser. That can often be after the actual cause of the error, so also consider the lines above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the error means a different character type was expected: not a letter.
In this case, you are missing a `{`. Go ahead and try:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('recieved', data);
});

process.stdin.emit('data', 'abc');
```

I expect this will work for you.